# Using plotly in python, how to make heatmap with annotations AND legend at same time?

Tags: python, annotations, plotly, legend, heatmap

In Python, using the latest version of plotly, how to make a heatmap that has both annotations and a legend?

The plotly library updated a few weeks ago and I can't find an working example for it anymore. The heatmap code seems fragmented where FigureFactory sub-library can make heatmaps with annotations easily, but the graph_objects sub-library can make heatmaps with legends. Nothing seems to do both at the same time and the documentation does not show a solution either.

Please help. Thank you.

I have tried the examples on both the following pages:
https://plot.ly/python/annotated_heatmap/

https://plot.ly/python/heatmaps/